# API endpoint works with JSON, not with raw text

Tags: json, api, postman, endpoint

I'm hitting an API endpoint with Postman. I put the settings for the `body` input to `raw`+`JSON` and passed the following body:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

This worked fine. However, when I set it to `raw`+`Text` and passed

`a=1&b=2&c=3` it returned the following error:

`"Invalid payload Error: There was an error deserializing the object of type InTowConnect._default35+RequestRequest. Encountered unexpected character 'a'."`

Does anyone know how I can approach debugging this?

Comment: `a=1&b=2&c=3` for this type of data, use content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Pass your a,b,c `xxx-www-form-url-encoded` key value pairs.

Comment: @AkshayBande When I change to `xxx-www-form-url-encoded` Postman forces me to enter each parameter in a separate box. So I can't input it as `a=1&b=2&c=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is it's own standard and not a text string. The parser you're sending to most likely isn't accepting a protocol other than the expected JSON. JSON != text.